# Similar matrix for numerical computations

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, eigenvalues, numerical-integration

I compute numerically a symmetric matrix $W$ from the flow of a ode. I have to check numerically if this matrix is definite-positive.
Two cases:

- either I use the Cholesky algorithm :ok
- or I compute the eigenvalues. It appears that in theory, $W$ has zero eigenvalues: $\lambda$ and numerically I can check that when I decrease the precision (absolute and relative) of the ode integrator, $\lambda$ becomes smaller while the other eigenvalues, let say $\gamma$, don't change.
  However, the ratio of $\frac{\lambda }{ \min(\gamma)}$ is not small ($10^{-5}$) with respect
  to the machine precision ($10^{-22}$).

**Question**: *How can I find a similar matrix $S$ (having the same spectrum) to $W$ so that $S$ is well conditionned to compute the eigenvalues (in the sense that $\lambda / \gamma$ will be closer to the machine precision) ?*

I tried simply to consider a scaling as : $W/|W|$ where $|.|$ is the Frobenius norm but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Cross-posted on Math.SE: [Similar matrix for numerical computations](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850704).